# Adding data to collection, which is more efficient?

Tags: c#

I am adding data to a collection, but I don't know which is more efficient.

Using a `foreach` loop,

```
internal class CollectionClass
{
    public List<string> ListData { get; set; }

    public CollectionClass()
    {
        ListData = new List<string>();
        string[] names = { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };
        foreach (var item in names)
        {
            ListData.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Or is this more efficent?

```
internal class CollectionClass
{
    public List<string> ListData { get; set; }

    public CollectionClass()
    {           
        ListData.Add("Matt");
        ListData.Add("Joanne");
        ListData.Add("Robert");
    }
 }
```

All logic suggests the latter, but with big data is this the case?

Comment: You could make a test and try it :), i think there is not much difference.

Comment: they are pretty much the same, but the first one is more conventional

Comment: Once you have the array, you can just call `AddRange`. No need for the foreach loop. But this question doesn't really make sense. If you are only adding three fixed values to the list, just do it in the constructor.

Comment: @CodyGray, awesome, I did not know that. That would be the most efficient way then? It was just test code. The data would be much bigger

Comment: There is likely no significant difference. You'd have to compile it and look at the disassembly to see what changed, and then if there was actually a difference, benchmark it to see which one is faster. This will be *impossible* to benchmark though; you aren't doing nearly enough work for the time difference to be measurable if it even exists. Pick the one you like better and that reads most clearly for you.

Comment: @CodyGray, thanks, I am coming from a VBA background and some things like this there are big differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no big difference unless you're adding like millions of entries, so select the code that you're more comfortable with.

Here is a benchmark of 4 different ways.

1) Array with loop (as in your first method).

2) Array with `AddRange`. Almost identical, but code is a bit nicer.

3) Using `Add` (as in your second method).

4) Using list initializer.

Sadly I cannot run each test more than 10,000 times because the dotnetfiddle.net gives a memory error, but you can copy the code and try it on your computer with higher number like 100,000. Anyway, the result is 1 and 2 are almost identical and faster than 3 and 4 which are very close. But you can see clearly how little the differences are even at 10,000 times of inserting 3 items. So it's really negligible.

[Link to fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TIzubG)

Test Results (in milliseconds):

> Test1: 6
>
> Test2: 6
>
> Test3: 2
>
> Test4: 2

Test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new CollectionClass();
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            c.Test1();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Test1:" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            c.Test2();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Test2:" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            c.Test3();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Test3:" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            c.Test4();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Test4:" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

internal class CollectionClass
{
    public List<string> ListData { get; set; }

    public void Test1()
    {
        ListData = new List<string>();
        string[] names = { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };

        foreach (var item in names)
            ListData.Add(item);
    }

    public void Test2()
    {
        string[] names = { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };
        ListData = new List<string>();
        ListData.AddRange(names);
    }

    public void Test3()
    {
        ListData = new List<string>();
        ListData.Add("Matt");
        ListData.Add("Joanne");
        ListData.Add("Robert");
    }

    public void Test4()
    {
        ListData = new List<string>(){ "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really reliable. Everytime the time is different, by +1/-1. It sort of gives you an idea though. I'd always go with the List initializer, IMHO cleaner and shorter.

Comment: @ArthurRey Yes, because the execution time is super fast (just a few milliseconds as you can see). That's why I said to run it at least 100k times (or better 1 mil) so it's much more reliable. But yes, it's just to give an idea. I also use the initializer, but you cannot use it if your items are coming from somewhere else (e.g. db) which is most likely the case for the OP because he mentioned a big number of entries.

Comment: Even if your items are coming from elsewhere (e.g. a db) you could still get an `IEnumerable` and use the `List` initializer instead of a `foreach`. It wouldn't make sense though, as you could have called `.ToList()` on your `IEnumerable`.